# How do I make this owner authentication work?

Tags: mysql, node.js, authentication, authorization

I have a problem with this code. I would appreciate it very much if someone could help me with this. If you have any missing information feel free to ask. Note: Iam using mysql2.

```
router.get('/restaurants/:name/:location/dashboard', userContoller.isLoggedInAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  const restaurantName = req.params.name;
  const restaurantLocation = req.params.location;

  console.log(`restaurantName: ${restaurantName}`);
  console.log(`restaurantLocation: ${restaurantLocation}`);

  try {
    // Query the database to retrieve the owner's information and the information for the specific restaurant
    const [ownerRows] = await db.promise().query(
      'SELECT * FROM owner WHERE id = (SELECT owner_id FROM restaurant WHERE name = ? AND location = ?)',
      [restaurantName, restaurantLocation]
    );
    const [restaurantRows] = await db.promise().query(
      'SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE name = ? AND location = ?',
      [restaurantName, restaurantLocation]
    );

    console.log(`ownerRows: ${JSON.stringify(ownerRows)}`);
    console.log(`restaurantRows: ${JSON.stringify(restaurantRows)}`);

    const owner = ownerRows[0];
    const restaurant = restaurantRows[0];

    console.log(`owner: ${JSON.stringify(owner)}`);
    console.log(`restaurant: ${JSON.stringify(restaurant)}`);

    // Check if the owner is logged in and has permission to access the dashboard
    if (req.owner && req.owner.id === restaurant.owner_id) {
      // Render the dashboard template and pass the owner's information and information for the specific restaurant to it
      res.render('role/admin/index', { owner: owner, restaurant: restaurant });
    } else {
      console.log('Owner not granted access to dashboard');
      // Redirect the owner to the login page
      res.render('errors/no permission');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

So I have this route and I want it to work. I have a user, owner and a restaurant table. In the owner table is the owner id and the user id as a foreign key referencing to the primary key in the user table. In the restaurant table there is a column called owner_id which is a foreign key referencing to the primary key in the owner table. What this basically means is that the user is the owner/admin of one or more restaurants. The problem is that somehow the owner does not have access to the restaurant even though he is connected with it.

Here is the middleware:

```
exports.isLoggedInAdmin = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('isLoggedInAdmin middleware called');
  
    if (req.cookies.one) {
      try {
        const decode = await jwt.verify(req.cookies.one, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  
        const [user] = await db.promise().query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?", [decode.id]);
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
        }
  
        const [owner] = await db.promise().query("SELECT * FROM owner WHERE user_id = ?", [decode.id]);
        if (!owner) {
          return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
        }
  
        if (user.id !== owner.user_id) {
          return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
        }
  
        console.log('Owner found:', owner);
        req.owner = {
          id: owner.id,
          user_id: owner.user_id,
        };
        next();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
      }
    } else {
      console.log('No owner found');
      next();
    }
  };
```

Here is the login system (focus on the cookie for the owner):

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(400).render("login", {
        msg: "Please Enter Your Email and Password",
        msg_type: "error",
      });
    }

    db.query(
      "select * from user where email=?",
      [email],
      async (error, result) => {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.length <= 0) {
          return res.status(401).render("login", {
            msg: "Please Enter Your Email and Password",
            msg_type: "error",
          });
        } else {
          if (!(await bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password))) {
            return res.status(401).render("login", {
              msg: "Please Enter Your Email and Password",
              msg_type: "error",
            });
          } else {
            const id = result[0].id;
            const token = jwt.sign({ id: id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
              expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
            });
            console.log("The Token is " + token);
            const cookieOptions = {
              expires: new Date(
                Date.now() +
                process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
              ),
              httpOnly: true,
            };

            // Check if the user is in the owner table
            db.query("SELECT * FROM owner WHERE user_id=?", [id], (error, result) => {
              if (result.length > 0) {
                // Set the cookie for owner
                res.cookie("one", token, cookieOptions);
                res.status(200).redirect("/restaurants/:name/:location/dashboard");
              } else {
                // Check if the user is in the manager table
                db.query("SELECT * FROM manager WHERE user_id=?", [id], (error, result) => {
                  if (result.length > 0) {
                    // Set the cookie for manager
                    res.cookie("two", token, cookieOptions);
                    res.status(200).redirect("/manager/dashboard");
                  } else {
                    // Check if the user is in the cook table
                    db.query("SELECT * FROM cook WHERE user_id=?", [id], (error, result) => {
                      if (result.length > 0) {
                        // Set the cookie for cook
                        res.cookie("three", token, cookieOptions);
                        res.status(200).redirect("/cook/dashboard");
                      } else {
                        // Check if the user is in the waiter table
                        db.query("SELECT * FROM waiter WHERE user_id=?", [id], (error, result) => {
                          if (result.length > 0) {
                            // Set the cookie for waiter
                            res.cookie("four", token, cookieOptions);
                            res.status(200).redirect("/waiter/dashboard");
                          } 
                        });
                      }
                    });
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Here is the log:

isLoggedInAdmin middleware called
Owner found: [ { id: 7, user_id: 42 } ]
restaurantName: BLOCKHOUSE
restaurantLocation: Pakistan
ownerRows: [{"id":7,"user_id":42}]
restaurantRows: [{"id":40,"name":"BLOCKHOUSE","location":"Pakistan","email":"2021erik.mettner@gmail.com","phonenumber":"012386763618","owner_id":7}]
owner: {"id":7,"user_id":42}
restaurant: {"id":40,"name":"BLOCKHOUSE","location":"Pakistan","email":"2021erik.mettner@gmail.com","phonenumber":"012386763618","owner_id":7}
Owner not granted access to dashboard

I know where the problem is. It is here:

```
// Check if the owner is logged in and has permission to access the dashboard
    if (req.owner && req.owner.id === restaurant.owner_id)
```

My Problem is that I dont know how to fix it. I want that the owner can access his restaurants. Only he, not any other owner.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).